# Exact match in capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm having a problem with Capybara 2.1 to match exact text.

I have a select form looking like this one :

```
<select class='tags-select'>
  <option>Tag 1</options>
  <option>Tag 2</options>
</select>
```

My test should select Tag 2

```
page.find('.tags-select', :text => 'Tag 2').click
```

Otherwise that keeps selecting  Tag 1 even with this Capybara config in my helper :

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.match = :prefer_exact
  config.exact = true
  config.exact_options = true
  config.ignore_hidden_elements = true
  config.visible_text_only = true
  config.default_wait_time = 10
end
```

I know that I can use some regex here to avoid the problem, but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong with that test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem, based on the query.rb file, is that the :exact option does not apply to the :text option:

```
def matches_filters?(node)
  if options[:text]
    regexp = options[:text].is_a?(Regexp) ? options[:text] : Regexp.escape(options[:text].to_s)
    return false if not node.text(visible).match(regexp)
  end
```

So the finder:

```
page.click_link('id', :text => 'Password', :exact => true)
```

Will match both of the following elements

```
<a id="id" href="#">Password</a>
```

and

```
<a id="id" href="#">Password Other</a>
```

Your approach might also be failing because your find method is actually returning the select list rather than the option (ie I believe you are clicking the wrong element). The following will click the right option, however you would still have the exactness problem.

```
page.find('.tags-select option', :text => 'Tag 2').click
```

To address the exactness issue, you need to pass the text value to the finder without using the text option.

If you are just selecting an option, use the `select` method as DevDude mentioned:

```
page.find('.tags-select').select("Tag 2")
```

If you really need to do a click instead, you could do:

```
page.find('.tags-select').find(:option, 'Tag 2').click
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you are using a text selector on an Element with multiple options. You should be using another specification for your selector that includes the option. Also, you should add a value for each option, as they are both equivalent (empty value). I would redo your work like this:

```
<select class='tags-select'>
  <option value="1">Tag 1</options>
  <option value="2">Tag 2</options>
</select>
```

And then try to select the option with this:

```
page.find('.tags-select').select("1")
```